# Should a Siyum Mishnayot for Avot be done after the 5th or 6th chapter?

Tags: siyum, pirke-avot-ethicsof

Pirkei Avot has only 5 chapters. The 6th chapter that is customarily recited on the Shabbat before Shavuot (and 3 more times during the summer), is actually a collection of *Braitot*.

If someone wanted to make a *siyum* on Mishnayot Seder Nezikin, can he do it if he only finished the first 5 chapters of Avot, and would this be the preferable way to do it, or should he include the 6th "chapter"?

Comment: I've got no real sources for this, but: A siyum is about the completion of a Torah-thematic body of work. Even though the 6th perek of Avos isn't "original" to the text, it is widely accepted as integrated into that body of work. It would therefore be inappropriate to disregard the standing tradition of Israel and disrespect the rabannim who contributed to the last perek by omitting it from your siyum.

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky I wouldn't disregard your statement. However, as you can infer, my motive for asking the question is going by the premise and a stricter definition of what the term "Siyum Mishnayot" really means. As a Masechta, Avot is 5 chapters. The 6th chapter is really a collection of braitot which was added for the purpose of a minhag. The question is whether the "strength" of the minhag applies to the rules of a siyum. I'm putting a bounty on this as an incentive.

Comment: What is a siyum mishnayot on a masechet anyways? AFAIK you just say *slik masechet ploni* -- no hadran, no kaddish.

Comment: Surely it depends on what you're planning on doing (or your intention). Since (as @Scimonster already said) there's no popular concept called a Siyum on a Masechet of Mishna. So once you're inventing a concept, feel free to go all the way and define it. :-)

Comment: I know that i did it after the 6th, but i have no sources...

Comment: @Scimonster Perhaps on the seder, with skipping that perek?

Comment: @Superplane Was that a siyum masechet, or a siyum seder?

Comment: @Scimonster ^^^

Comment: @Shokhet It was both.